# How to uninstall programs from /usr/local/bin?

Tags: centos, centos6

I'm looking at Python2.7 in /usr/local/bin. I believe I installed it a long time ago, and I want to uninstall it. I see the size of it is 9776. If I use `rm` on it, how do I remove the rest of it? It can't be like 10 kb can it?

Comment: `rpm -q -f /usr/local/bin/python2.7` to find the package name, then `yum remove <package_name>`

Answer (score 3):

How did you install it? Hopefully you used yum? If that's the case, then just use your package manager to remove it:

```
$ sudo yum remove <package_name>
```

If you did not use yum, well good luck. This is an excellent reason to never install anything on a linux system without using its package management system. If you *do* need to install extra things that aren't included in the distro's package repo, then put it somewhere completely separate, like in `/opt` or somesuch.

WARNING: it's quite likely that a bunch of things on your system depend on python to be installed. I would highly recommend you leave it there.

Comment: Big +1 for the warning. I once symlinked Python 3 over Python 2 and the entire server was basically screwed. Thankfully it was a testing VM...

Answer (score 2):

Distributions generally install with `prefix=/usr`, your case seems like a manual install with `prefix=/usr/local`.  Some software (namely GNU ones) offer a `make uninstall` option to cleanup these, but I have no idea whether python does that; you may have to look at (inside `/usr/local`) `lib/libpython2.7.so`, `lib/python2.7/`, `lib/pkgconfig/`, `share/man/man1` and manually remove those looking related.

Usually I'd recommend manual installations to either:

1. Install to a temp dir and tar it up for tracking files later: `make DESTDIR=/path/to/temp && tar cf /path/to/package.tar -C /path/to/temp .`; or
2. Install to `/opt/name-version`, e.g. in your case `./configure --prefix=/opt/python-2.7`.  You can create symlinks in `/usr/local/bin` (and other dirs like `man`, `pkgconfig`), so that removing the software takes only a `rm -r` and pruning dead symlinks, which a zsh glob does nicely.

Comment: Packages. Use the effing package manager ([fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm)). Don't rely on tarballing.

Comment: @DeerHunter There are other ways you'd get files there, like `make install`.  The package manager does not help if you're trying to install the most recent commit.